# Ubuntu 16.04 takes 30 minutes to shutdown or restart

Tags: 16.04, shutdown, swap, restart

**Ubuntu 16.04** takes **30 minutes** to shutdown or restart.

This usually happens when Computer is running for a long time and Swap is being used.

I have Core i5 with 4 GB RAM, 4 GB Swap and Hard Disk Drive (HDD).
When i was going to restart the computer after closing all applications, 1.5 GB of RAM was in use and 1.6 GB of Swap was in use (in System Monitor).

**Note:** Computer shutdowns and restarts in 4 seconds when I have booted into Ubuntu and used some programs and Swap was not used during this duration.

As soon as the Computer is booted in Ubuntu for long duration and Swap is being used then  it takes 30 minutes to shutdown or restart

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45673/how-can-swapoff-be-that-slow) question describes a case similar to what you are experiencing. Try verifying it by running `sudo swapoff -a` before shutting down. Reactivate swap with `sudo swapon -a`

The problem is that if that's you case you can't do much about it.

Comment: There were two Outcomes:
1. When was RAM Not Available to adjust the swap therefore having this error:
"/dev/dm-0: swapoff failed: Cannot allocate memory"
And shutdown/restart problem persists and takes more than 30 minutes.

2. When RAM was Available to adjust swap:
Swap Data is transferred to RAM and Ubuntu Restarts or Shutdowns properly within 4 seconds.

Comment: Q1: Is there a patch to fix this bug? And if yes, then which patch is it and how to implement it?

Q2: Is there any workaround available for this?